# ¿Como puedo hacer para que un valor cambie en cada iteracion en python?

Tags: python, bucles

Lo que se supone que quiero lograr, es que a cada vuelta, se sume el valor anterior
Por ejemplo:
al inicio tienes 100 dolares, y se suma el 10%, por 10 meses cada mes, lo que intenté lograr, es que se sumara cada vez el valor de el interés (inicialmente 100) pero que con el tiempo fuera (100, 110, 121, etc)

```
periodos = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de peridos que quieres calcular: "))
dinero = float(input("Ingresa la cantidad de dinero que quieres calcular: "))
porcentaje = float(input("Ingresa el porcentaje de cada periodo "))

for i in range(periodos):
    calculo = (porcentaje * dinero) / 100
    total = dinero + calculo 
    print("Este es el total de todo:  " + str(total))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes de añadir una nueva variable para que se vaya actualizando en cada iteración del for. Prueba esté código y verás como funciona. Puede optimizarse más eliminando la declaracion de la variable totalDinero, pero así funcionará al 100%.

```
periodos = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de peridos que quieres calcular: "))
dinero = float(input("Ingresa la cantidad de dinero que quieres calcular: "))
porcentaje = float(input("Ingresa el porcentaje de cada periodo "))

totalDinero = 0

for i in range(periodos):
  calculo = (porcentaje * dinero) / 100
  totalDinero += calculo 
  print("Este es el total de todo:  " + str(totalDinero))
```

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente solo  cambias el total por dinero así vas acumulando el total de dinero en cada interacción del for

```
periodos = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de peridos que quieres calcular: "))
dinero = float(input("Ingresa la cantidad de dinero que quieres calcular: "))
porcentaje = float(input("Ingresa el porcentaje de cada periodo "))

for i in range(periodos):
  calculo = (porcentaje * dinero) / 100
  dinero=calculo + dinero
  print("Este es el total de todo:  " + str(dinero))
```